# Puppet template with string instead of array

Tags: yaml, puppet, erb, hiera

I am using an erb template in Puppet to make a config file.
I am using the following code:

```
databasename = <%= @db_name %>
```

the `db_name` variable is defined in the following yaml format:

```
databases::db_name:
- DB_PLACEHOLDER
```

The problem is, when I generate a file from the template, Puppet puts square brackets around my variable substitution like below. I do not want the square brackets?

```
["DB_PLACEHOLDER"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`["DB_PLACEHOLDER"]` in Puppet and Ruby (since you are using ERB) is syntactically an array with one element: `"DB_PLACEHOLDER"`. If you do not want `databases::db_name` to be an array, then you need to specify it as a string and not an array in your yaml that Hiera is looking up from.

Your example below specifies `databases::db_name` as an array.

```
databases::db_name:
- DB_PLACEHOLDER
```

You can change the type of `databases::db_name` to a string by using the appropriate yaml syntax:

```
databases::db_name: DB_PLACEHOLDER
```

In case the type inference during the Hiera lookup from yaml does not cast to string, you can always explicitly specify the value as a string in the yaml:

```
databases::db_name: 'DB_PLACEHOLDER'
```